# How to SELECT only value changes in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table with values according to a Period

I wish to select only the changes

Example:

Table columns:

```
Member
Status
Period
```

Table data:

```
Member  Status  Period
----------------------
     A       X       1
     A       X       2
     A       Y       3
     A       Y       4
     B       X       1
     B       X       2
     B       X       3
     B       Z       4
```

I would like the query to return something like this

```
   Member A Status change X to Y Period 2 to 3
   Member B Status change X to Z Period 3 to 4
```

I'm having issues because Oracle doesn't allow to order by in sub queries

Any idea of a query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a window function for that:

```
select *
from (
  select member,
         status, 
         period,
         lag(status) over (partition by member order by period) as prev_status, 
         lag(period) over (partition by member order by period) as prev_period
  from the_table
) 
where status <> prev_status
```

Comment: Thank you, this relsoved my issue